# Convert Varchar to Float still gives error

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

Can someone please help me. Why do i still get still error? Error converting varchar to float

I have to get p.menge (float) and p.wert (varchar) to one float row.

p.wert hold this different values -->

[image]

```
SELECT a.AdressNrADR,k.monat,k.Jahr,p.Id_kopf,a.name + ' '+ a.vorname as Name,p.Artikel, p.tag,CAST(CASE WHEN p.wert = '' THEN p.Menge  
            WHEN p.wert IS NULL THEN p.Menge  ELSE (ISNULL(CASE WHEN p.wert = 'A' THEN '1' WHEN p.wert = 'B' THEN '0' WHEN p.wert = 'C' THEN '0' WHEN p.wert = 'D' THEN '0' ELSE p.wert END,0)) END AS FLOAT) AS Menge

            FROM   ( ( ( ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
            LEFT JOIN  ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id =  p.Id_Kopf)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse =  a.AdressNrADR)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR =  gl.AdressNrADR)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR =  g.GruppeADR
```

Comment: cast p.menge  as varchar.

Comment: You've failed to tell us *what error you're getting*.

Comment: Sorry Error converting varchar to float

Comment: @jarlh my goal is to have menge and wert as float so why should i cast menge as varchar?

Comment: Because you have non-numeric values in the p.wert column.

Comment: @jahrl Yes but in the case i say that A -> 1 and so on so there should be only numeric values left to cast

Comment: You need to provide sample data as text, not a picture. Why? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 I see 0,5 in your sample. That can't be converted to a float. I would suggest you think twice about using float anyway as it very rarely is a good datatype choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.AdressNrADR,k.monat,k.Jahr,p.Id_kopf,
   a.name + ' '+ a.vorname as Name,p.Artikel, p.tag,
   cast(CASE WHEN p.wert IS NULL or p.wert = '' THEN p.Menge
   ELSE ISNULL(CASE 
        WHEN p.wert = 'A' THEN 1 
        WHEN p.wert = 'B' THEN 0 
        WHEN p.wert = 'C' THEN 0 
        WHEN p.wert = 'D' THEN 0 
        ELSE TRY_CONVERT(float, p.wert) END,0) as float) AS Menger
   FROM   ( ( ( ZUS_Monatsreport_Kopf k
            LEFT JOIN  ZUS_Monatsreport_Pos p ON k.Id =  p.Id_Kopf)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_Adressen a ON k.Adresse =  a.AdressNrADR)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_GruppenLink gl ON a.AdressNrADR =  gl.AdressNrADR)  
            LEFT JOIN  ADR_Gruppen g ON gl.GruppeADR =  g.GruppeADR
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but still same error, Error converting varchar to float :S

Comment: @user2210516, I assumed your values in "wert" column is convertible to float or one of 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'. If it is not then use try_convert instead. I will edit it with TRY_CONVERT (MS SQL 2012 and later).